# Can't Retrieve One to Many Relationship Data In Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I have a bit strange of problem about retrieving one to many relationship data in Laravel.

**Model**

```
// JobTypes model
public function jobs()
{
    // one type of job has many jobs
    return $this->hasMany('App\Jobs', 'id'); // id refer to jobs.id
}

// Jobs model
public function job_types()
{
    // one job only belongs to one type of job
    return $this->belongsTo('App\jobTypes');
}
```

**Pivot table**

```
 Schema::create('jobs_job_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('jobs_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('job_types_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('jobs_id')->references('id')->on('jobs');
        $table->foreign('job_types_id')->references('id')->on('job_types');
    });
```

**Controller**

```
$data = \App\JobTypes::paginate($items);

    return view('jobs.index', compact('data'))->with(array('showData' => $showData, 'count' => $count))->withItems($items);
```

**View**

```
@foreach($data as $jobType)
        <td>
          @foreach($jobType->jobs as $category)
            {{ $category->name }}
          @endforeach
        </td>
    @endforeach
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: recommend following general Laravel naming conventions as much as possible, especially in your models, as this will save you a lot of headache later and will make your code easier to read for other Laravel devs. i.e. `App\jobTypes` should be singular and capitalized `App\JobType`, with its corresponding database table in snake_case and lowercase `job_types`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a pivot table for a [one-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in Laravel.  The child relationship (the "many" side) can simply store the id of the parent model it belongs to.

(See also my comment above about following general [Laravel naming conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).)

Models:

```php
// JobType.php
class JobType extends Model
{
    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Job');
    }
}

// Job.php
class Job extends Model
{
    public function job_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\JobType');
    }
}
```

Migrations:

```php
// create_job_types_table.php
    Schema::create('job_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        ...
    });

// create_jobs_table.php
    Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('job_type_id')->unsigned()->index();
        ...

        $table->foreign('job_type_id')->references('id')->on('job_types');
    });
```

Comment: I dont know, it's now solved with pivot table for one to many relationship. Is this bad?

Comment: A one-to-many relationship is about as basic as you can get.  Pivot tables are generally only used/needed for many-to-many relationships.  Using them here is **nonstandard** to say the least.  If you really insist on using a pivot table, you will need to declare both sides of the relationship as `belongsToMany` (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: How about one to one relationship in Laravel? Do we need pivot table for it?

Comment: @SeadLab no, a one-to-one relationship doesn't require a pivot table either.  Here's a helpful resource I've used in the past when deciding what relationship to use and how to implement it: https://medium.com/hackernoon/eloquent-relationships-cheat-sheet-5155498c209

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
// JobTypes model
public function jobs()
{
    // one type of job has many jobs
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Job_Type::class, 'job_id');
}

// Jobs model
public function job_types()
{
    // one job only belongs to one type of job
    return $this->belongsTo('App\jobTypes','job_type_id','id');
}
```